# OutputCache and Response modification

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, caching

I have an action method that calls third-party library which writes image content into `Response.OutputStream` of the `HttpContext`.
Then this action method returns `EmptyResult`.

I decided to implement output caching for it, but it does not work.

I put `VaryByCustom` on it, but `GetVaryByCustomString` is never firing for calls to this action method.

Although another action method which returns current `datetime` wrapped in `JSON` and has the same `OutputCacheAttribute` setup as the first one works as expected and `GetVaryByCustomString`  method is being called.

Could you tell me what can be the reason for such a behavior?

Comment: Are you adding any additional headers into the response incl cookies ?

Comment: @Symeon Hi. I do modify headers but do not add any cookies

Comment: I know for certain adding a cookie header to the response will stop the output cache from working. Maybe there are other headers that do the same. Worth experimenting on that route I would say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out was was the problem. Third-party service was returning content as 'chunked', that is why caching was not working.